# SWT - Best Code Procedure to Open a Dialog From a Button

Tags: java, swt

On my main GUI application there is a button that opens separate dialog.  The new dialog has a table with a list of printers. I can not get this to work.  I am pretty sure it is do to populating the table.  Below is the code that I am using to try and make this work.

```
Button plotButton = new Button(composite, SWT.PUSH);
   plotButton.setText("Select Plotter");
   plotButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
       public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          startPrinterListOperation();              
          showFooBarDialog();
       }
  });
```

Here is the showFooBarDialog() Method

```
private void showFooBarDialog() {
  apd = new FooDialog(null);
  apd.create();
  apd.getShell().setSize(700, 400);
  apd.open();      
}
```

In the FooDialog I am trying to populate a table with printers that is accumulated from a server side calls.

```
private void startPrinterListOperation() {
  listOp = new AplotPrinterListOperation(appReg.getString("aplot.message.GETPRINTERLIST"), session);
  listOp.addOperationListener(new MyOperationListener(this) {
     public void endOperationImpl() {
        try {
            printers = (ArrayList<PrinterProfile>) listOp.getPrinters();
        }
        finally {
           listOp.removeOperationListener(this);
           listOp = null;
        }
     }
  });
  session.queueOperation(listOp);
}
```

That method basically starts a operation that goes to the server and collects available printers and then Stores them in a ArrayList, this process can take a second or two.

So when FooDialog tries to open and populate the table, I immediately get a null pointer error on this line

```
 viewer.setInput(parentDialog.getPrintersArray());
```

I think it is where the `ArrayList` has not been completed so it is returning Null.

1. Is there somewhere else I should be calling `startPrinterListOperation()` instead of the button click?
2. Is there a way to make the `showFooBarDialog();` not execute until a certain about off time?
3. I may be completely off on how I am trying to do this.  Should the `startPrinterListOperation()` method be in the `FooDialog` instead of the Main Gui?
4. How would you as SWT programmers address this issue?

**Edit**
Adding table code

```
private TableViewer createPlotterTable(Composite parent) {
  Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE); 

  viewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
  createColumns(parent, viewer);
  Table table = viewer.getTable();
  table.setHeaderVisible(true);
  table.setLinesVisible(true);
  viewer.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
  viewer.setInput(parentDialog.getPrintersArray());

  // Layout the viewer
  GridData gridData = new GridData();
  gridData.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
  gridData.horizontalSpan = 2;
  gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
  gridData.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
  gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
  viewer.getControl().setLayoutData(gridData);

  return viewer;
}
```

**Edit**

The table code is in separate class not in the main GUI class.

```
public class AplotPlotterDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {
   private AplotBaseDialog parentDialog = null;
```

Comment: In your code snippets is no line `viewer.setInput(parentDialog.getPrintersArray());`. Please provide the code containing this line.

Comment: Ok, now where is the `parentDialog` defined in your last code snippet?

Comment: Have you tried calling the printer code in a new thread, and assign the results to a synchronized variable so that once the variable is free, the dialog opens with the data.. just an idea.

Comment: Yes - please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321978/learning-threads-running-a-method-only-after-the-other-has-finished